# how to change a javaEE app database from mySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jpa, java-ee-7

I developed a JavaEE app using EclipseLink JPA framework and MySQL database, it worked fine on my machine, but when I tried to change the database to Heroku PostgreSQL I encountered the following exception :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at DAO.ClientDAO.<init>(ClientDAO.java:17)
    at controllers.authServlet.doPost(authServlet.java:49)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:694)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLogins(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2481)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:752)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:123)
    ... 33 more
```

the changes that I made:

I added org.postgresql.Driver dependency to pom.xml.

I modified persistence.xml with the new database information.

I connected the database to eclipse.

I regenerated the entities from the tables(client and agent).

is there any idea of what causes this problem?

Comment: Looks like an issue (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/885 ) with EclipseLink trying to decrypt your password, a problem particular to this password string. You might try a different password string, or pass in the datasource as a parameter instead similar to http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2008/04/eclipselink-and-datasources.html

Comment: @Chris since i can't change the password I tried the second solution